# Start streaming from specific minute in ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I have a m3u8 file and I want to stream it using ffmpeg . The problem is that I don't need the first 20 minutes included in the video . Is there any way to start streaming that m3u8 file from the 21 minute ?

Comment: This is off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: I have asked this question some other places but I didn't get any proper answers . I was hoping somebody here can help .

Comment: Try [superuser](http://superuser.com/). Or just look into the manual. (hint: the `-ss` option).

Comment: oh I found that -ss parameter is what I really needed , Thanks dear Roland